# PHP scrape title, IF

Tags: php

Basically I am wanting to get the title of pages,

I want it to return TRUE if title is like:

```
<title>
Site Name - Page</title>
```

but return false if title is like:

```
<title>
Site Name - </title>
```

How can I go about inputting a URL into an fopen, checking the title and then returning TRUE/FALSE depending on the title, we only want it to be TRUE if there is text after the "-" in the title tag.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $url = "http://www.sitename/" . strtolower($r['z'] . "." . $r['x']) . "/";
    $file = fopen(($url),"r") or die ("Can't read input stream");
    $text = fread($file,32768);
    if (preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/is',$text,$found)) {
            $title = 1;
    } else {
            $title = 0;
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: You may want to use an XML parser instead of a regex, at least to capture the title content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified your code for opening the URL, but I do see that your regex could be improved upon.  Try this...

```
/<title>.+\s-\s.+<\/title>/is
```

where

`.+` ensures there is atleast on character before and after the dash, and
`\s-\s` ensures that there is a " - " separating the first and second part of the title tag.

Comment: Hi there, that works great - although I've changed how I want to do it. Basically I want to return false now if this is found in the page content: "<h2>There are no direct matches to your search.</h2>" - how would I go about searching for this in the page and if found.. return false?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to match this as well...

    /<h2>There are no direct matches to your search.</h2>/s

Since this is static text that is not really changing, you could also try the `strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )` function.

Comment: Yeah but thats why I'm asking on here, I am completely useless with regular expressions, if you could help me I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Whoops!  Didn't quote that regular expression properly.  It would be the following:
`/<h2>There are no direct matches to your search.</h2>/s`
But using strpos would probably be more efficient, use:
`strpos($text,'<h2>There are no direct matches to your search.</h2>') !== false`  For examples, see [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php[link]

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the title check in a function like this:

```
function check_title($url){
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  return (preg_match("/\<title\>(.+)-(.+)\<\/title\>/i", $html))? TRUE: FALSE;
}
```

and you could use it like this:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $url = "http://www.sitename/" . strtolower($r['z'] . "." . $r['x']) . "/";
  $title = check_title($url);
}
```